# Measuring text length in pixels with php(using GD library)

Tags: php, gd, pixel

I would like to measure how long a text is in pixels with php I am using [imagettfbbox](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) function from GD library. I dont understand what the parameter angle is(it definately effects the return value), but what angle is this?

The first parameter is to specify the font size in points and then return in pixels. But doesnt that also depend on DPI? One pt with 72dpi is equal to 1px, 1pt with 96dpi is equal to 1,33px, isnt it?

What I am trying to do is to end the text in a html element with ... when the text exceeds size of element. The `text-overflow: ellipsis;`  is not an option as it doesnt work with multiline text. If anybody has any other ideas, please share.

Comment: 'angle' is the rotation of the text

Comment: so normal text has angle 0??

Comment: yes..from php.net: `The angle in degrees, with 0 degrees being left-to-right reading text. Higher values represent a counter-clockwise rotation.`

Comment: look at the comments on php.net: [function.imagettfbbox](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php). There are some functions that could help you.